# Binding to SelectedItem

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, binding, combobox

I use the WPF ribbon library in my application and defined a combobox like this:

```
<r:RibbonComboBox>
    <r:RibbonGallery SelectedItem="{Binding ActiveCamera}">
        <r:RibbonGalleryCategory ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableCameras}"/>
    </r:RibbonGallery>
</r:RibbonComboBox>
```

The binding sources are defined in the window's `DataContext`:

```
public Camera[] AvailableCameras
{
    get ...
}

public Camera ActiveCamera
{
    get { return _activeCamera; }
    set
    {
        if (_activeCamera != value && value != null)
        {
            _activeCamera = value;
            Notify("ActiveCamera");
            'Some more logic that is not related to UI
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Active camera set to " + value);
    }
}
```

Camera is only a simple class with properties `Name` and `id`.

The `ActiveCamera` is set in the ViewModel's constructor to the first item of the `AvailableCameras`. I could verify that in code.

However, if I start the application, the combobox is empty. The debug output states this after starting the application:

```
Active camera set to 713x BDA Analog Capture
```

If I click the combobox, the camera seems selected:

[image: Combobox with selected Item]

Futhermore, the following debug output is added:

```
Active camera set to
```

If I then click somewhere else in the window, the combobox is closed and remains empty. The following debug output is added:

```
Active camera set to
```

But this behaviour does not seem consistent. If I click the combobox and then somewhere else in the window again, the first camera is selected and the following debug output is added:

```
Active camera set to           (on click on the combobox)
Active camera set to 713x BDA Analog Capture
```

This all would not be a problem, if the bound `SelectedItem` would actually be selected on application startup. Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have noticed the same behavior and it is very frustrating. I stumbled on this question looking for another issue, but I wouldn't have guessed the problem by this question title.

Comment: @DBueno: I fear not. I can't remember exactly since it's been a while. But I would have posted an answer if I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem but I cant remember if TwoWay binding is default here.

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ActiveCamera, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Also make sure when you set the initial camera it is through the Property `ActiveCamera` and not the field `_activeCamera` to ensure `Notify` is called.

These would be the first simple steps to try out, please comment on this answers if this does not help and I try to see if there is something I can do.

---

Another wild guess. I notice that your collection is a array. This does not notify any changes to the collection so if the items is added later it would notify the GUI. As the item appears in the list I guess this is not the problem. You could try yo change it to `ObservableCollection<Camera>`.

My guess from reading your post better is that you are no beginner here and are well aware of the nuances of WPF databinding. Is that correct?

Comment: Explicitly defining `TwoWay` results in the same behaviour. Notify is definitely called.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the nuances of databinding ;). The `ItemsSource` is an array that is never touched again. It seems to be related to the specialties of the ribbon controls.

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled upon a [RibbonGallery example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2010/08/19/using-ribbongallery-control.aspx) that does not seem to have this issue (i.e. on start-up the selected item *is* showing correctly). They have an interesting solution to managing RibbonGallery data. There is a class they've created, `GalleryData<T>`, that has a SelectedItem and a CategoryDataCollection properties for the SelectedItem and ItemsSource bindings respectively. Those bindings are being handled by a style targeting the RibbonGallery type. When I removed the SelectedItem binding from the style and moved it to the gallery control itself, there was no selection on start-up. It seems odd to do those bindings in a style, but if that's what it takes then I guess it's alright. Hope that helps.